# Wagtail Admin UI: create HomePage without a Site leads to AttributeError crash

Tags: wagtail

I'm new to Wagtail, and I'm exploring the Bakery demo [that is a great demo, by the way!].  I can produce an AttributeError, 'NoneType' has no attribute 'startswith'".

The problem is that the Preview code in the Admin UI assumes that there is a site for every Page.  But in my case there is no site yet.

I got to this point by not paying enough attention to the warnings in the Admin UI.  But still, a little defensive programming in the Wagtail admin code will protect against this error.

Steps to reproduce:

- Get the Bakery demo up and running.
- Wonder about creating my own site, as a sibling of the Bakery site. Note the absence of a 'Sites' entry in the Admin UI sidebar, and decide to create a new HomePage thing via Pages -> Add child page (to Root) -> select HomePage as the type of the new child of Root.
- Read this warning, but pay no attention: "These is no site set up for this location. Pages created here will not accessible at any URL until a site is associated with this location. Create a site now"
- Create a new HomePage thing.
- Click "Preview".
- Uh-oh.

The problem is that the Preview code in the Admin UI assumes that there is a site.  But in my case there is no site yet.

It seems to me that the code that does the Preview operation can check in advance for an associated Site.  Or perhaps the code can catch the AttributeError and compose an error response of its own.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like more of a bug report than a question... please can you report it at https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/issues ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moved to github, as suggested by gasman. I apologize - I misread the wagtail.io website about where to get support.